# Proving linearity of a twice-differentiable function with $(D^2 f)_p =0$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, linear-transformations

Let $U$ be a connected open subset of $ \Bbb R^n$ and $f: U \to \Bbb R^m$ is twice-differentiable everywhere and $(D^2f)_p=0$ for all $p$. How do I show that $f$ is linear?

Comment: Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436864/question-over-function-twice-differentiable-if-d2-f-is-constant) for example.

Comment: Edit: the post linked solved my problem. Thanks!